# New to Python - Why does this program produce an array of length 1000, instead of 50000, and why are the first 50 values of the array equal to 0?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

Why does this program produce an array of length 1000, instead of 50000, and why are the first 50 values of the array equal to 0?

```
import numpy as np
arr_growthrates = np.linspace(0, 4, 1000)
arr_initial_x = np.random.random((1, 50))

l = []
for k in arr_growthrates:
    for m in arr_initial_x:
        iteration = 100

        v = []
        v.append(m)

        for i in range(iteration):
            v.append(k * v[i] * (1 - v[i]))


        l.append(v[100])

print(len(l))
print(l)
```

Because this involves a loop within a loop, and the first loop has 1000 iterations, and the second loop has 50, and because I append values to l after the second loop, I expected l to have a length of 50000, but instead it has a length of 1000. Also why are the first 50 values in l equal to 0?

Comment: @AtomProgrammer `arr_growthrates` is `np.ndarray`. If it was a number, it would've failed with `TypeError`

Comment: @AtomProgrammer I thought that in line 2 I define arr_growthrates as an array with 1000 values, equally spaced between 0 and 4, and that a for loop in arr_growthrates with just cycle through each value?

Comment: Try printing `len(arr_initial_x)`. It has two dimensions, and the outer one is 1. I think, you meant, `np.random.random(50)`.

Comment: Thank you @bereal np.random.random(50) has worked, the list now has 50000 values, however the first 50 are still 0?

Comment: @bereal why did      np.random.random((1, 50))      not work? I thought that this code defines an array with 1 row and 50 columns, all with random values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @cookiecainsy You were iterating over something with 1 row (like `[[1,2,3...]]`), so it's only 1 iteration instead of 50. As for the zeros, try printing debug info in the loop or using debugger. What's the formula you're implementing?

Comment: @bereal the Formula is a logistic map, how do I print bug info in the loop?

Comment: @bereal I've just realised that the 0s are to be expected for low values of arr_growthrates,  thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem was with the shape of  `np.random.random((1, 50))`. It results in an array of the shape `(1, 50)`, which is equivalent of a list `[[a1, a2, ...]]` from the iteration point of view. Instead, use just:

```
 arr_initial_x = np.random.random(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `arr_initial_x = np.random.random((1, 50))` returns an array with this shape (1, 50).

So, inside the loop `for m in arr_initial_x:` there is only 1 round done because only one object read (*e.g. the whole array of 50 items*).

I guess you would have a shape equal to (50,), and you can have this result with this command `arr_initial_x[0].shape`.